# Import WhatsApp Conversation To My App

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

I am developing whatsapp conversation archiving app and i want import conversations from whatsapp.

There is "Export Chat" button at whatsapp and it is opening uiactivityviewcontroller but how can i my app to that list ?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application

Comment: First you have to figure out what type of file WhatsApp is exporting.

Comment: @rmaddy I know it's zip but my problem is adding my app to sharing options.

Comment: @NicolaGiancecchi yes no luck.

Comment: @rmaddy Problem is not supporting zip files, problem is my app does not show at whatsapp sharing. Other apps like gmail etc.. there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems WhatsApp is using a `UIActivityViewController` instead of a `UIDocumentInteractionController`. So there is no way to get your app listed unless your app implements the proper app extension. I see the Google Drive app listed as an option and your screenshot shows the Pocket app. Those two apps must implement the appropriate app extension to appear on the list.

See the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/). You probably need to implement either an Action or Share extension to get listed.